# Is the TAB character bad in source code?

Tags: php, javascript, coding-style, standards

I'm pretty familiar I guess with both Zend and PEAR PHP coding standards, and from my previous two employers no TAB characters were allowed in the code base, claiming it might be misinterpreted by the build script or something (something like that, I honestly can't remember the exact reason). We all set up our IDE's to explode TABs to 4 spaces.

I'm very used to this, but now my newest employer insists on using TABs and not spaces for indentation. I suppose I shouldn't really care since I can just tell PHP Storm to just use the TAB char when i hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, but, I do. I want spaces and I'd like a valid argument for why spaces are better than TABs.

So, **personal preferences aside**, my question is, **is there a legitimate reason to avoid using TABs in our code base**?

Keep in mind this coding standard applies to PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: Hehe, here comes the tab/space flame war ...

Comment: Argh! Not the Tabs Vs. Spaces holy war! Surely everyone can see that Tabs are superior! :)

Comment: I don't know any scripts/interpreter that fails with tabs.
The most annoying thing is when you have it mixed and some editors interpret tabs as 8 spaces.

Comment: some of the text editors show tab character as 8 characters and some show it as 4 characters

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. Seems like a genuine question, not a "what do you think is better" question.

Comment: `explode("\t")` or `.split("\t")` give different results than `explode(" ")` and `.split(" ")`.  Sometimes you *have* to use both tabs and spaces in your code.

Comment: I don't agree with those that would close this question as not constructive. The OP doesn't want discussion; they just want arguments against tabs.

Comment: I've heard that the "NT" in Windows NT stood for "No Tabs".  Apparantly Microsoft went all spaces decades ago. ;-)

Comment: Let's re-open this

Comment: @AlienWebguy: At least move it onto P.SE and see how that flies.

Comment: @mario and other closers - It's not appropriate for the P.SE format.  This is a question about code.  The OP explicitly stated she is not interested in personal preference, but "legitimate reasons to avoid tabs".  How is that not code related?

Comment: @gilly3: Of course it isn't. But tabs and spaces most certainly aren't code.

Comment: @mario — they are with the power of [Acme::Bleach](https://metacpan.org/module/Acme::Bleach) ;)

Comment: I think she wants to know if tabs could/would break her code. Zend forbids tabs but doesn't say why. PEAR forbids tabs and says `This helps to avoid problems with diffs, patches, SVN history and annotations.` but that sounds like a "dont have developer A use tabs and developer B use spaces" argument.

Comment: ahem.. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @vascowhite we've already closed and reopened this. This is a legit question and I'm personally very interested in hearing an answer. The OP doesn't want to know WHY you think spaces or tabs are better

Comment: @alien There aren't any 'legitimate' reasons that can't be argued against. It comes down to preference, either personal, corporate or otherwise. Therefore it doesn't belong here. The comment fest alone backs up the fact that this question should be closed.

Comment: Possibly, though I have heard rumors - whether they be true or otherwise - that tabs can be interpreted differently cross-platform. I've honestly never bothered to research it myself which is why I'm so curious to hear an answer to this question.

Comment: I didn't realize this was such a controversial topic lol! All I really want to know is if there's nothing wrong with TABs, why would both Zend and PEAR specifically say they are not allowed?

Comment: I can't believe this was closed again. Read the message - she was looking for FACTS, REFERENCES, and SPECIFIC EXPERTISE and wanted to avoid OPINION.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: That's pretense. The question is clearly tagged [coding-style]. Decorating it with requests for "facts" doesn't make it so. Last comment by OP makes it clear that syntax woes were an euphemism. It was clearly about style advise. -- Regarding your question: yes. It was an established plattform standard on PCs to substitute tabs for 8 spaces, on Macs it was 10 spaces, and some homecomputer systems 6 spaces. The later redeclaration to 4 spaces on Windows and IDEs is therefore non-standard (on PCs), henceforth sometimes ascribed to typing laziness. Ambiguity is the only topic here.

Comment: @mario that's probably all she needed to hear, about the cross-platform differences :) That being said, I don't think this question is harmful to SO or was not constructive. On the contrary you just taught me something new about Tab characters. I think people here jump on the close train too early - I mean, why even have a 'coding-style' tag if using it will get your questions closed?

Comment: Related questions on Programmers: [Why do some languages recommend using spaces rather than tabs?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/121167/why-do-some-languages-recommend-using-spaces-rather-than-tabs) and [Tabs versus spaces—what is the proper indentation character for everything, in every situation, ever? \[closed\]](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e).

Comment: It seems that diligent, conscientious programmers - the type that may end up making a framework like Zend or Pear, prefer spaces for the above mentioned reasons. All the lazy programmers I know prefer tabs. Also, sometimes there is alignment between different parts of the line (not just the left-most non white-space character) which gets messed up when tabs are used. So personally I avoid them

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> is there a legitimate reason to avoid using TABs in our code base?

I have consulted at many a company and not once have I run into a codebase that *didn't* have some sort of mixture of tabs and spaces among various source files and **not once has it been a problem.**

Preferred? Sure.

Legitimate, as *in accordance with established rules, principles, or standards*? No.

### Edit

> All I really want to know is if there's nothing wrong with TABs, why
>   would both Zend and PEAR specifically say they are not allowed?

Because it's **their** preference. A convention they wish to be followed to keep uniformity (along with things like naming and brace style). Nothing more.

Comment: I guess you don't work with Python then :)

Comment: Your guess is incorrect.

Comment: Why would you vote to close the question and then provide an answer hoping to get points? That's mean.

Comment: That's not what happened. I voted to *migrate* the question to programmers.stackexchange.com when someone suggested it in the comments. Then a diamond moderator came along and closed it as *not constructive.* There was nothing I could do.

Comment: I personally would have accepted this answer. Least biased and addressed the issue about why adopted standards don't allow Tabs.

Comment: @webbiedave I see. I apologize for assuming the worst :(

Comment: Have you had problems when you have a mixture of tabs and spaces in the same file?

Answer (score 30):

**Tabs are better**

- **Clearer** to reader what level each piece of code is on; spaces can be ambiguous, espcially when it's unclear whether you're using 2-space tabs or 4-space tabs
- **Conceptually makes more sense**.  When you indent, you expect a tab and not spaces.  The document should represent what you did on your keyboard, and not in-document settings.
- Tabs **can't be confused with spaces** in extended lines of code.  Especially when word warp is enabled, there could be a space in a wrapped series of words.  This could obviously confuse the readers.  It would slow down paired programming.
- Tabs are a **special character**.  When viewing of special characters is enabled on your IDE, levels can be more easily identified.

Note to all coders: you can easily switch between tabs and spaces using any of JetBrains' editors (ex. PHPStorm, RubyIDE, ReSharper, IntelliJIDEA, etc.) by simply pressing CTRL + ALT + L on Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Comment: And I quote myself: "So, personal preferences aside, my question is, is there a legitimate reason to avoid using TABs in our code base?"

Comment: Yes, there is only **one** legitimate reason that I know of: this is when you are working on a repository, and converting the spaces to tab characters would cause git to see them as changes.  In these cases, you should use the coding standards provided by the repo.

Comment: Git is configurable to ignore tabs vs spaces difference.

Comment: I disagree, Tabs can be a different size on different computers and PRINTERS!

Comment: full explanation why spaces are better - http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/2312

Answer (score 21):

Spaces are better than tabs because different editors and viewers, or different editor settings, might cause tabs to be displayed differently. That's the only legitimate reason for avoiding tabs if your programming language treats tabs and spaces the same. If some tool chokes on tabs, then that tool is broken from the language point of view.

Even when everybody in your team sets their editor to treat tabs as four spaces, you'll get a different display when you have to open up your source code in some tool that doesn't.

Comment: No, that's why tabs are better then spaces (since developers can configure their editor to show indentation at the size they like while having a consistent codebase).

Comment: Tabs are clearly better than spaces if you're using a non-monospaced font :)

Comment: It's worth nothing noticing that the most of "coding standards" out there forbid tabs, as well as (meta-)languages in which indentation has a meaning (e.g. python, yaml)

Comment: There may be reasons why tabs are better than spaces, but the OP isn't asking for them.

Comment: @AldoStracquadanio maybe you can provide the OP links to these coding standards which forbid tabs and state their reasoning for doing so.

Comment: @larsmans: Your answer is "Spaces are better", your comment is "There may be reasons why tabs are better". Why don't you complete your answer and unbias it by turning it into a pro/con list, so the OP actually sees the benefits of both, instead of your single argument. Your +1s are clearly from fans of spaces, since there's a real lack of content here.

Comment: @Leigh: because (a) the OP asks for reasons why tabs are better than spaces, not for extended discussion, and (b) I've been a badge-carrying member of the church of spaces for quite a few years now ;)

Answer (score 6):

The most important thing to worry about is *being consistent* about always using the same indentation scheme - having a confused mix of tabs and spaces is living hell, and is worse then either pure tabs or pure spaces. **Therefore, if the rest of the project is using tabs you should use them too**.

Anyway, there isn't a clear winner on Tabs vs Spaces. Space supporters say that the using only spaces for everything is a simper rule to enforce while Tabs supporters say that using tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment allows different developers to display the tab-width they find more comfortable.

In the end, tabs-vs-spaces is should not be a bid deal. The only time I have seem people argue that one of the alternatives is strictly better then the other is in indentation-sensitive languages, like Python or Haskell. In these mixing tabs and spaces can change the program semantics in hard to see ways, instead of only making the source code look weird.

Answer (score 2):

Ever since my first CS class, tabs have always been taboo. Reason being, tabs are basically like variables. Different IDE's can define a TAB as a different number of spaces. Speaking from a Visual Studio/NetBeans/DevC++ perspective, all have the capacity to change the 'definition' of a TAB based on number of desired spaces. So if you have 4 spaces defined, there is no way that you can know if my IDE says 3 spaces or 5 spaces. So if anyone happens to use a space-based indentation style and someone else uses TABS, the formatting can get all jacked up.
As a counter-point, however, if the 'standard' is to always use tabs, then it really wouldn't matter since the formatting will all appear the same - regardless of the number of defined spaces. *But* all it takes is one person to use a space and the formatting can look horrid and get really confusing. This can't happen when using spaces. Also, what happens if you don't want to use the same spacing between functions/methods, etc? What if you like using 4 spaces in some cases and only 2 in other cases?

Comment: So your main argument against tabs is that space-lovers screw it up for everyone.  Sounds more like a reason to get rid of the space-lovers to me.  :)  But it's not a tabs vs spaces issue...it's a *consistency* issue.  You have the same issue when someone introduces tabs; you just don't know about it right away, cause no one else uses tabs, so they never bothered to change their tab settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen build scripts that parse source code and generate documentation or even other code.  These kind of scripts usually depend on the code being in an expected format, and frequently that means either using spaces (or sometimes tabs).  Perhaps these scripts *could* be modified to be more robust by checking for tabs *or* spaces, but frequently you are stuck with what you've got.  In that kind of an environment, consistent formatting becomes more important.